# Android 4.2.2 signal 11 SIGSEGV: Unable to match class WebResourceRequest and WebResourceError

Tags: android, webview, segmentation-fault

I'm working on an app that works perfectly fine when running on Android 6.0. When I try to run it on 4.2.2, it crashes completely with Signal 11 SIGSEGV.

Just before this crash, the logical shows this error:

```
dalvikvm: Unable to match class for part: Landroid/webkit/WebResourceRequest;Landroid/webkit/WebResourceError
```

This tells me that I'm using two classes that aren't available in 4.2.2. Besides the fact that none of the tools caught this, I made sure that it wouldn't happen because every place where I use those classes I put the correct @TargetApi annotation before the methods that use these classes. For example:

```
@RequiresApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
   ...
}
```

and

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
   ...
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Or maybe these two errors aren't related to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@TargetApi` just an annotation and suppress the Lint error. You need to manualy check build version and use allowed classes and methods

For example

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
  return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
}
```

added in Api level 21 but there are deprecated method added in Api level 11

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
  return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
}
```

You can create several instance of `WebViewClient` with build version depending or simply override deprecated methods

Comment: But these two functions are callback functions. How do I "manually check the build version" around a method declaration? I can't wrap them in an  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M). I tried using @RequiresApi instead but I got the same result.